# Clear a form value in Angular

Tags: angular

I have an Angular form that contains a select box. The select box has an onChange event which should trigger a method to clear an input field also found in the form however nothing seems to be working.

**html**

```
<div class="ui-g-12 ui-md-12">
    <div class="ui-g-6 ui-sm-12">
        <div class="input-container">
            <label for="identityTypeId">Identity document type*</label>
            <p-dropdown [options]="identityDocTypeArr"(onChange)="clearIDNumberField()" formControlName="identityTypeId" id="identityTypeId" placeholder="Select"></p-dropdown>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="ui-g-6 ui-sm-12">
        <div class="input-container">
            <label for="identityValue">Identity number*</label>
            <input id="identityValue" type="text" formControlName="identityValue" size="50" placeholder="0000000000000" (blur)="validateSouthAfricanID()">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**TS**

```
clearIDNumberField() {
    this.offerFormGroup.get("identityValue").reset(); 
}
```

My forms name is [formGroup]="offerFormGroup"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use setValue to set/clear the value of your input

```
this.offerFormGroup.controls['identityTypeId'].setValue("");
```

Comment: Thanks this is the answer

Comment: @skydev I'm glad I could help.

Answer (score 1):

Hello [skyDev](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5853403/skydev) it looks like your code

```
 clearIDNumberField() {
    this.offerFormGroup.get("identityValue").reset(); 
  }
```

is not working because your reference the correct name of the formControl which if I am correct should `identityTypeId`. Hence what is wrong is actualy the control name been referenced. That been said the code should

```
  clearIDNumberField() {
        this.offerFormGroup.get("identityTypeId").reset(); 
      }
```

instead of

```
clearIDNumberField() {
    this.offerFormGroup.get("identityValue").reset(); 
  }
```

It might have been of good help if you had posted the contents of your formGroup variable too, but all the try the above changes.

Answer (score 0):

Try This,

```
   clearIDNumberField() {
     this.offerFormGroup.reset(); 
   }
```

Comment: This resets the entire form and not just the specific input field

Answer (score 0):

You can clear the forms value, in this case all the controls that makes up the form:

```
clearIDNumberField() {
     this.offerFormGroup.reset(); 
   }
```

This will reset the form to normal.

Comment: I just need to clear an input field, not the whole form

Comment: Oh okay. Then *** this.offerFormGroup.get("identityValue").reset();*** should work.  Can you post the  code in your component.ts file so we can have a feel of what is going on.

Answer (score 0):

You can Try below function

```
clearIDNumberField() {
 this.offerFormGroup.identityValue = ''; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can reset with:

```
this.offerFormGroup.get("identityValue").setValue('')
```

and

```
this.offerFormGroup.controls["identityValue"].setValue('');
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `setvalue('')` method.